# Should I put a moisture barrier under tile on a basement floor?

Tags: flooring, basement

I bought porcelain tile for my basement.. Should I put Ditra down in order to prevent any moisture? Is there a cheaper way? I had tile put in the other room and there is white powder that comes up through the grout. I don't want this happening in the other rooms.

Comment: Was the other room sealed?

Answer (score 1):

There are waterproofing/isolation membranes that can be painted on such as [RedGuard](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-RedGard-1-gal-Waterproofing-and-Crack-Prevention-Membrane-LQWAF1/100169081) and [Mapelastic](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Mapei-Mapelastic-Aqua-Defense-1-gal-Waterproof-Membrane-01953/202524402). They're coatings you paint on.

Much cheaper and easier to use than sheet style barriers. The sheet membranes like ditra provide better waterproofing and isolation to prevent cracks which are important in areas with a lot of moisture like showers or slabs with cracks.

Years ago when I tiled my basement with porcelain tile I used a penetrating concrete sealer that you just spray on. Haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ditra functions as a floating substrate. If your slab should happen to contract or expand as the house settles (By as little as 1/32") you may have broken grout lines or cracked tiles. The ditra will allow the slab to expand while the tile surface remains static.

If you have no cracks anywhere on the slab, you are probably okay. I did my basement this way, and two years later no issues whatsoever. If you live in an earthquake prone area, might want to think twice. I think Ditra is overpriced, and try to avoid the added cost as much as possible.